# jquery get a textbox in a table

Tags: jquery

I would like to select a textbox being dynamically created by an asp.net server control (listview) For each row in the table I need to run some javascript functionality over it.

Below I am trying to select the textbox based off of the name haveing the text. Is there a "better" way of doing this?

```
      $('#tblNewAttendees tr').each(function() {
   var test = $(this).find('input[name$="txtFirstName"]').val();
      });
    }
```

Html code

```
<table>
     <thead>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
           <tr>
                 <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName")%>'      
                runat="server" Width="80px" />
                 </td>
          </tr>
     </tobdy>
</table>
```

Comment: So there isn't a better method for grabbing the textbox besides, what I am doing or using a unique class?

Comment: The table is constructed through a listview. There are X txtFirstName textboxes. But adding a unique class does seem better, then relying on the id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign a specific CSS class to all those text boxes, and then use class selectors to select those.

Suppose you have assigned `myClass` as CSS class value. Then use the following to select them -

```
$('#tblNewAttendees tr').each(function() 
{
    var test = $(this).find('input.myClass').val();
});
```

The reason is, as far as I remember, the names that you assign to a text box is replaced by ASP.NET with something new after it parses the document. Suppose you have a text box whose name is `myBox`. Then after the page is parsed, its name may become something like `ct_1001_myBox_123` or something. So it's better to use a CSS class to select them in the client side.

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following to simplify it (no need to do a .each() then a find within that) :

```
$('#tblNewAttendees tr input[name$="txtFirstName"]').each(function() {
     var test = $(this).val();
}
```

You may want to change your markup to give the asp textbox a class and select based on the class name, since .net will rename the ID property.

Answer (score 2):

You could give your textbox a unique class name and use the class name as the selector.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" class="myClass" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName")%>' runat="server" />
```

Then in your script just select by the class

```
  $('.myClass').each(function() {
   var test = $(this).val();
      });
    }
```